# "ContentTypeId" crawled property issue

Tags: search, crawling, managed-property

I want to get all items with CT derived from some ParentCT using FullTextSqlQuery by ContentTypeId. And there are no results returned. 
Query looks like:

`SELECT ContentTypeId FROM SCOPE() WHERE CONTAINS(ContentTypeId, '"0x01*"')`

Where:

1. ContentTypeId is the managed property associated with both of crawled properties. (There are 2 crawled propetries with same name - "ContentTypeId")
2. '0x01' - some parent CT id

Also:

1. Index have been reseted
2. Full crawl have been done
3. Crawled property settings => "Include values for this property in the search index" **checked** in both of crawled propetries named "ContentTypeId"
4. Crawled property settings => "Content using this property" => "Sample documents:" has

> There are zero documents in the index using this property

in both of crawled propetries named "ContentTypeId"

Answer (score 1):

Did you check "Include values for this property in the search index" for both of the ContentTypeID crawled properties?

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164182.aspx

"On the Edit Crawled Property page, if you want to include values for the crawled property in the search index, select the Include values for this property in the search index check box. This option makes values for the crawled property searchable when a full-text search is used. Crawled properties are usually searchable only when a property-based search is used."

Comment: Checked. Is "ContentTypeId" crawled property associated with list item "ContentTypeId" field? May be it is somthing else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a full crawl since you made any changes to the managed properties?

Comment: Yup. Also search index had been reseted. =\

Answer (score 0):

Taking a hint from this [forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/d4e168b5-0d5a-4cf5-aec0-682ec21ec896)
you could try the following Powershell commands to investigate the properties of the "ContentTypeID" Managed Property you created and mapped.

```
ps:> $ctID = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication "<searchappname>" -Identity "ContentTypeID"
ps:> $ctID | fl
```

Take a look at the "**Retrievable**" and "**FullTextQueriable**" properties.

Answer (score 0):

While doing some investigations on an other problem I have noticed that the ContentTypeID managed property only has values for items that are Office Documents. So either this is a "by design" limitation or another bug of SharePoint ;-)